# Django validation best practice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I'm implementing a custom Django form which just contains an email address field.

As well as the usual email field type validation, I want to add some extra checks, such as whether this email address has already been used for this user etc.

What is the best practice way of doing this using class-based views (FormView, in this case, obviously) ?

Should I put the validation code:-

1. in the form_valid() method of the FormView or
2. in the clean_email() method of the form class

Option 2 seems the neatest to me, but if I go that way, I need to pass the user into the form (and pop it in the init method) so that the clean_email method can use to do database lookups which doesn't seem quite right either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latter approach since you know it would be neatest one.
Another benefit of going via this approach will be that you can identify which function your validation error occurred which might be helpful when you want to add more validations in future.

And then what other ways do you have to check if user is already present in the system. 
You have to add the logic in view then.